# Contact Form Extensions - Checkbox Templating

Tags: plugin-contactform, plugin-contactformextensions

Cannot for the life of me get checkbox values to display in a HTML email template using the Contact Form extensions plugin.

Form snippet:

```
<input type="hidden" name="message[type]" value="">
<p><input type="checkbox" class="styled-checkbox" name="message[type][]" id="New" value="New">
<label for="New">New</label></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" class="styled-checkbox" name="message[type][]" id="Used" value="Used">
<label for="Used">Used</label></p>
```

And the email template snippet:

```
{% if submission.message['type'] %}
<p style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.625; color: #51545E; margin: .4em 0 1.1875em;">Type of Quote: {{ submission.message['type'] }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Does anyone have a clue about this? I have tried many variations, the above is just one of them. Pulling my hair out ;)

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close. In your input you have `name="message[type][]"`. The little `[]` at the end there means means the data will be stored in an array, something like:

```
submission: {
  message: {
    type: ['New', 'Used']
  }
}
```

You have two options here:

**Option one**

You can change your inputs to be `name="message[type]"` instead of `[type][]`. This should result in a data structure more like you're expecting

```
submission: {
  message: {
    type: 'New'
  }
}
```

Then your conditional check can be kind of like you have it, but this won't allow multiple values (not sure if you want those or not).

**Option Two**

Update your conditional check and output to properly output the array values. This would mean something more like:

```
{% for type in submission.message.type %}
  <p style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.625; color: #51545E; margin: .4em 0 1.1875em;">
    Type of Quote: {{ submission.message.type }}
  </p>
{% endfor %}
```